# SVG and Responsive issue

Tags: javascript, css, svg, responsive-design, raphael

i have an issue with this home page -> http://novustest.altervista.org/

the map is displaying correctly on big screens but i want to make it more flexible, i want that the map resize automatically if i reduce my window browser. How can i do that?

This is my code, it's very simple. I have only one html page and 2 js file.

This is my HTML page:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
.italy{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myMap" class="italy">

        </div>
        <script src="raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script src="map.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the link to jsfiddle but it doesn't work...

https://jsfiddle.net/ye0b2qvp/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute in the svg tag and play with `viewBox`

View here :

https://jsfiddle.net/fm024028/2/

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 1500 600" ...
```

Comment: Thanks...it works but now i have this problem -> http://novustest.altervista.org      
the region are overlapping...why?

Answer (score 1):

Your SVG has embedded styling in it that's making it 1920x1080.

See [this article](http://soqr.fr/testsvg/embed-svg-liquid-layout-responsive-web-design.php) for more clarification on the matter.